# scalable tools to build kNN graph over sparse data

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, k-nn, search-engine

I'm looking for **scalable** tools to build **kNN** graph over **sparse** data points.

The dimension and number of data points can be both up to millions.

What I have tried already:

- [sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph.html): which does brute-force search for sparse data, giving quadratic time.
- [flann](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/): only supports [dense arrays](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/blob/master/src/python/pyflann/index.py#L118)
- [pysparnn](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pysparnn): the running time is not very satisfatory (maybe because it's written in Python)
- knn search in [mlpack](https://www.mlpack.org/index.html): which only supports dense data
- [scipy.spatial.KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html): which converts the sparse data to dense one
- [SparseLSH](https://github.com/brandonrobertz/SparseLSH): which is implemented in Python, so I'm not quite sure about the scalability
- [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/): it seems to only support indexing documents, instead of sparse features.

  - the reason I thought of elasticsearch is: knn over sparse data can be framed as retrieving the top-k "documents" in IR.

Thanks for any comments/answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is,

**L2Knng: Fast Exact K-Nearest Neighbor Graph Construction with L2-Norm Pruning**

They have multiple runtime options specifically for different kinds of datasets (including **sparse** data). The link for the same is : http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/node/1162